# Golang POST request from one to another docker container

Tags: docker, rest, go

I have a server in one docker container (port 5044) and client in other docker container (port 4545). I want to send POST request from client to server but i get an error message "Post "http://127.0.0.1:5044/check": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:5044: connect: connection refused".

```
json, err := json.Marshal(x)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
resp, err := http.Post("http://127.0.0.1:5044/check", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(json))
//Handle Error
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("An Error Occured %v", err)
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
//Read the response body
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalln(err)
}
return string(body)
```

I can send post request using postman and everything is ok.
I tried to connect to test internet service (https://ptsv2.com/) and it works as well. It seems like golang doesnt want to conenct to the local server form docker :/

Comment: Did you created a network to comunicate between cpntainers

Comment: They communicate using bridge network. I can easily ping server from client container.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` in Docker almost always refers to the current container, not another container.  You might look at [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for the host names you can use in a typical Compose-based setup.

Answer (score 0):

your docker app is accessible from it's "external port" with Postman

But to allow them to communicate together they need to be on the same network

the easiest way to do it is to use a docker-compose (instead of manually creating the neworks) [official link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#specify-custom-networks)

```
version: '3'
services:

first:
  build:
    context: ./your-first-app
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - '1800:1800'
  networks:
    my-network:

second:
  build:
    context: ./your-second-app
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
    - '1801:1801'
  networks:
    my-network:

networks:
  my-network:
```

your network is declared at the end of the line, and it's linked to both your Docker service via the tag networks (below ports)

Comment: Compose creates a network named `default` for you automatically; you do not need the manual `networks:` blocks, and I'd suggest deleting all of them in the name of simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to connect to the docker container is by using the container name e.g. `http://app_one:5044/check`, you can find the container name by using the `docker ps` command. in order to connect with the container name, all containers have to be in the same network.

###### But if you want to use IP this is the way.

Each container has a different IP address, in order to connect from one container to another you need to know the container IP address that you want to connect. 127.0.0.1 is not the container IP, it's the host IP.

you can to find the IP address of the container by this command, `docker inspect your_container_name` you will see the IP in networking section

```
"Networks": {
  "bridge_network": {
    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1",
    "IPAddress": "172.18.0.37",
    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
    "IPv6Gateway": "",
    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
  }
}
```

in my example `172.18.0.37` is my container IP address. so I need to use that by to communicate e.g. `http://172.18.0.37:5044/check`

be aware that IPAddress if the container can change when you restart the container so it's better to use container name

Comment: ok but if I have a client server app I don't know which ip dns will assign to client and which to server.  Is there any way to do it automaticly?

Comment: then you need to use the container/service name instead of IP. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Find your service name from your `docker-compose.yml` file for the server and replace this:

```
resp, err := http.Post("http://127.0.0.1:5044/check", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(json))
```

with this:

```
resp, err := http.Post("http://<serviceName>:5044/check", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(json))
```